# Minikube driver=podman, has anyone been able to get it to work?

Tags: kubernetes, centos, fedora, minikube

Has anyone been able to get minikube to work with --driver=podman?

I have tried Fedora 30,31, CentOS7,8, RHEL7,8 all with the same results.

```
# # minikube start --driver=podman --container-runtime=cri-o --cri-socket=/var/run/crio/crio.sock
  minikube v1.9.2 on Fedora 30 (vbox/amd64)
✨  Using the podman (experimental) driver based on user configuration
  Starting control plane node m01 in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
E0409 16:50:17.654306   30363 cache.go:114] Error downloading kic artifacts:  error loading image: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
  StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create host timed out in 120.000000 seconds
  Restarting existing podman container for "minikube" ...

  Failed to start podman container. "minikube start" may fix it.: driver start: get kic state: "podman inspect -f {{.State.Status}} minikube" failed: exit status 125: Error: error getting image "minikube": unable to find a name and tag match for minikube in repotags: no such image


  minikube is exiting due to an error. If the above message is not useful, open an issue:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
```

It feels like cri-o needs to be installed and running.  I have done that but still get the same results.

Update 1:

```
# minikube start --driver=podman --container-runtime=cri-o --cri-socket=/var/run/crio/crio.sock --network-plugin=cni --enable-default-cni --v=1
  minikube v1.9.2 on Fedora 30
✨  Using the podman (experimental) driver based on user configuration
  Starting control plane node m01 in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
E0415 12:38:49.764297   24903 cache.go:114] Error downloading kic artifacts:  error loading image: Error response from daemon: 404 page not found
  StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: creating: create kic node: create container: failed args: [run --cgroup-manager cgroupfs -d -t --privileged --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --tmpfs /tmp --tmpfs /run -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro --hostname minikube --name minikube --label created_by.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=true --label name.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --label role.minikube.sigs.k8s.io= --label mode.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --volume /root/.minikube/machines/minikube/var:/var:exec --expose 8443 --publish=127.0.0.1::8443 --publish=127.0.0.1::22 --publish=127.0.0.1::2376 gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.8] output: Error: invalid option type "exec"
: exit status 125
  Restarting existing podman container for "minikube" ...

  Failed to start podman container. "minikube start" may fix it.: driver start: get kic state: "podman inspect -f {{.State.Status}} minikube" failed: exit status 125: Error: error getting image "minikube": unable to find a name and tag match for minikube in repotags: no such image


  minikube is exiting due to an error. If the above message is not useful, open an issue:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
```

I'm happy to flip over to Fedora 31 or CentOS if needed.

Update 2: Set selinux to permissive with same failure.

Update 3: Per suggestion from @vbatts the minikube start cmd is pretty close to working.  It seems crio sock lives in /var/run/crio/ so I updated that path.  Now I'm getting the following...

```
[root@test ~]# minikube start     --network-plugin=cni     --enable-default-cni     --extra-config=kubelet.container-runtime=remote     --extra-config=kubelet.container-runtime-endpoint=/var/run/crio/crio.sock     --extra-config=kubelet.image-service-endpoint=/var/run/crio/crio.sock     --driver=podman
  minikube v1.9.2 on Fedora 30
✨  Using the podman (experimental) driver based on user configuration
  Starting control plane node m01 in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Downloading Kubernetes v1.18.0 preload ...
    > preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4: 542.91 MiB
E0416 09:25:47.539842    1632 cache.go:114] Error downloading kic artifacts:  error loading image: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.18.0 on Docker 19.03.2 ...
    ▪ kubelet.container-runtime=remote
    ▪ kubelet.container-runtime-endpoint=/var/run/crio/crio.sock
    ▪ kubelet.image-service-endpoint=/var/run/crio/crio.sock
  Enabling addons: default-storageclass, storage-provisioner
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
```

And now these cmds hang ....

```
[root@test ~]# kubectl get nodes
^C

[root@test ~]# minikube status
E0416 09:30:30.741722   10795 api_server.go:169] unable to get freezer state: cat: /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/libpod_parent/libpod-16c8b830eb8e4cb0baa576e98d8343fdab1dacea8db4a6a6d84bbb8fbc7c0f92/kubepods/burstable/pod7dd7509c8b924aaaebd697cbbc2aff89/aa2abeea32b056907d33590baf5fc0c213b718cc8b16b548f251326675f32337/freezer.state: No such file or directory
Error: non zero exit code: 1: OCI runtime error
^C
```

Comment: Can you add these flags to minikube start command: --network-plugin=cni \
    --enable-default-cni  also add --v=1 flag to show all warnings ?

Comment: @MaggieO I updated my post with the additional flags

Answer (score 2):

Firstly make sure that you configured [Minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) properly: [minikube-configuration](https://asciinema.org/a/142924).

You have to specify network plugin and enable it, also it is important to add image-service endpoint  for runtime: `/var/run/crio/crio.sock`:

```
$ sudo minikube start \
    --network-plugin=cni \
    --enable-default-cni \
    --extra-config=kubelet.container-runtime=remote \
    --extra-config=kubelet.container-runtime-endpoint=/var/run/crio.sock \
    --extra-config=kubelet.image-service-endpoint=/var/run/crio.sock \
    --driver=podman
```

Please take a look: [minikube-crio-podman](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/01/29/podman-kubernetes-yaml/), [crio-minikube](https://books.google.pl/books?id=0JmZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA296&lpg=PA296&dq=crio+minikube+start&source=bl&ots=sxbiWGdCZE&sig=ACfU3U3nA4G-w_A24nb1WU6S2hLdO9RX2A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8hP_51ezoAhXL_KQKHS8fCtkQ6AEwB3oECAwQOA#v=onepage&q=crio%20minikube%20start&f=false).

Comment: Hi @vbatts, Thanks for commenting.  I'm updating my post with new status...

Comment: Can you provide output of command: sudo podman logs minikube ?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, it seems to work on Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20.04) using the instructions from [minikube podman docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/podman/):

```
❯ minikube version
minikube version: v1.15.1
commit: 23f40a012abb52eff365ff99a709501a61ac5876

❯ minikube config view
- container-runtime: cri-o
- driver: podman

❯ minikube start
  minikube v1.15.1 on Linuxmint 20
❗  Using podman 2 is not supported yet. your version is "2.2.1". minikube might not work. use at your own risk.
✨  Using the podman (experimental) driver based on user configuration
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Creating podman container (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB) ...
❗  Unable to create dedicated network, this might result in cluster IP change after restart: podman network not implemented yet
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.19.4 on CRI-O 1.18.4 ...
  Configuring CNI (Container Networking Interface) ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default

❯ minikube status
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured

❯ kubectl run httpd --image=httpd
pod/httpd created

❯ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
minikube   Ready    master   8m46s   v1.19.4

❯ kubectl get pods
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
httpd   1/1     Running   0          2m5s
```

Answer (score 0):

Struggled a while to get Minikube running with Podman. I think there is a bug in in the installation of Podman, because the package "containernetwork-plugins" doesn't get install in the latest version.

What i did is to install the latest version of containernetwork-plugins manually, using cri-o as container runtime. Below a working Bash script which works, in my case (March 2024).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ensure the script is run as root
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi

# Install podman and containerd
apt-get -y install podman containerd

# Install kubectl
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

# Add Kubernetes apt repository
curl -fsSL https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/Release.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/ /" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list

# Add cri-o apt repository
curl -fsSL https://pkgs.k8s.io/addons:/cri-o:/prerelease:/main/deb/Release.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/cri-o-apt-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/cri-o-apt-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.k8s.io/addons:/cri-o:/prerelease:/main/deb/ /" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cri-o.list

# Update apt and install Kubernetes packages
apt-get update
apt-get install -y cri-o kubelet kubeadm kubectl

# Install minikube
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube && rm minikube-linux-amd64

# Setup minikube
minikube delete --all
minikube config set driver podman
minikube config set container-runtime cri-o

# Install containernetworking-plugins
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/golang-github-containernetworking-plugins/containernetworking-plugins_1.1.1+ds1-3ubuntu0.23.10.2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i containernetworking-plugins_1.1.1+ds1-3ubuntu0.23.10.2_amd64.deb

# Start minikube as non-root user
```